# Error in React Native Project: Missing Required Architecture for CoreModules, Firebase, and Other Targets in Xcode 14.3.1 with Rosetta

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, rosetta

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to run a React Native project in Xcode 14.3.1. I receive a warning stating that

> CoreModules, DoubleConversion, FBLPromises, FirebaseCore,
> FirebaseCoreExtension, FirebaseCoreInternal, FirebaseInstallations,
> FirebaseMessaging, GTMSessionFetcher, GoogleDataTransport,
> GoogleToolboxForMac, GoogleUtilities, GoogleUtilitiesComponents,
> Protobuf, RCTAnimation, RCTBlob, RCTImage, RCTLinking, RCTNetwork,
> RCTSettings, and 47 other targets are missing a required architecture.

To address this warning, I tried building with Rosetta, but after a successful build, I encounter an issue when starting the simulator. I receive the following error:

> "Unable to boot device because it cannot be located on disk. The
> device's data is no longer present at
> /Users/ibrahim/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/10542D30-BC9E-4457-BB6A-25B15CD66322/data.
> Use the device manager in Xcode or the simctl command line tool to
> either delete the device properly or erase contents and settings."

Has anyone faced a similar issue while building with Rosetta or encountered this specific problem? Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-react-native/issues/895
or
By using the command xcrun simctl erase all in Terminal, I was able to fix the problem.
or
Close the Simulator.app, Xcode.app, etc.
Try the following commands in Terminal
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService    
rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator

Answer (score 0):

1. List available devices `xcrun simctl list devices`
2. Open device manager in xcode->window->Devices and Simulators->Simulators and check if your simulator exists or create a new one